# WP e-commerce: Paypal Express checkout not working with Paypal IPN

Tags: paypal, wordpress, e-commerce, paypal-ipn

MY Paypal IPN code is executed only when payments are made without checking out from the wp e-commerce shopping cart. If payments are made directly through paypal, then my IPN works fine.

However, if payments are made through the wp e-commerce checkouts then my IPN code will not get executed at all.

In my wp setting, I've made sure the followings are done:
my API username, password and signature.
IPN is enabled.

In my paypal account, I've made sure the followings are done:
IPN URL is set and IPN is enabled.

Does anyone have the same problem? I've done a lot of research and I'm still not able to solve this problem. I don't have "Bad Behaviour Plugin" which is suggested by some as the reason to this blocking of execution.

Thank you!!